# dispatch_semaphore_wait doesn't work with concurrent background NSOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, semaphore, nsoperation

**Edit:** In fact semaphore works perfectly with background NSOperation, the problem was that sometimes operation becomes cancelled even **before** it has chance to start, which produced extra call to dispatch_semaphore_signal and allowed passing of two dispatch_semaphore_wait without stopping thread.

---

My iOS app uses sqlite database as data storage (without CoreData due to historical reasons). sqlite crashes when one database connection is accessed by few threads simultaneously, so to make it possible I use dispatch_semaphore_wait with semaphore activated as dispatch_semaphore_create(1) on database opening.

After I implemented one of database access methods as NSOperation (I need cancellation functional) my app started to crash and I realised that dispatch_semaphore_wait does not pause thread even when database is already busy. This usually happens when I perform quick database call from the main thread which overlaps with bigger call wrapped in to NSOperation.

Here are code which creates NSOperation:

```
self.loadOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    [database openDatabase];
    // read some data
}

self.loadOperation.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriorityLow;
self.loadOperation.qualityOfService = NSOperationQualityOfServiceUtility;
self.loadOperation.completionBlock = ^{
        [database closeDatabase];
};

NSOperationQueue* backgroundQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[backgroundQueue addOperation:self.loadOperation];
```

And here is how I manage access to DB:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    if ( self = [super init] ) {
        databaseOpenSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)openDatabase
{
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(databaseOpenSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);  
    // open DB
}

- (void)closeDatabase
{       
    // close DB
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(databaseOpenSemaphore);
}
```

Comment: To which class do the two snippets of code correspond to? Can you give more context to the code you posted so we better understand what happens from your main thread and what from the other thread you assume that causes the crash?

Comment: This two snippets belong to two different classes which are quite big, so I copied only problematic pieces. I also added screenshot of the threads state at the moment of the crash.

Comment: the thing is that you don't provide enough context for us to link all pieces together, you don't need to post the whole source code.

Comment: @Cristik Thank you for looking on this thing, but it's very hard to provide more detailed context - there are a lot of things which happens around. I hope I somehow narrowed the focus, I caught the moment when execution pass semaphore unexpectedly - please see my Edit inside the post.

Comment: @Cristik In fact it was my mistake, and you was right - it was not visible because I simplified code too much. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**dispatch_semaphore_wait works with concurrent background NSOperation.**

But next time I should consider that background NSOperation with low priority could be cancelled after it's added to a queue but **before** it has time to start. In such case in my implementation completionBlock for this operation made extra call to dispatch_semaphore_signal which produced "mysterious" fault of dispatch_semaphore_wait